# Jquery Html getiing contents

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have some issue with jquery. i have some 



 tags after each **ul li closed**

i want to pick content of particular p tag when it's li has been clicked

Here in my HTML

```
<div class="content">
      <p><span style="color: #d10018; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15pt; line-height: normal; text-align: left; background-color: #ffffff;">VALUES CREATE TRUST</span></p>
<h1><span style="font-size: 9pt;">From customer </span></h1>
<ul>
<li>Appreciations</li>
</ul>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag">Your company culture is our groundwork. We select the candidates according to professional, objective criteria, but also pay attention that every candidate supplements the company/team best possible. Because pleasure at work increases the life quality of every individual.</p>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag">With personal contact, we ensure that the special needs of our customers are fulfilled precisely.</p>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag">Everybody benefits from our selection process. Candidates receive a comprehensive feedback with the results of the potential diagnostics. You as a company benefit from the appreciative handling of every candidate.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul>
<li>Structured procedure for enjoying mutual success.</li>
</ul>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag"> successful decisions.</p>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag">position.</p>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag">every position.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<ul>
<li>Using innovations.</li>
</ul>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag".n high demand also among competitors.</p>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag">Advantage is assured by well-founded branch experience and knowledge of current developments in the respective markets.</p>
<p style="margin-left: .75in;">. our above-average dedication and effort.</p>


<p style="margin-left: .75in;" class="ulptag">&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".content>ul").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {            
     console.log($(this).nextUntil(":not(p)").text());
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T99WA/1/)

UPDATE: Here is the explanation

- $(".content>ul") will pick all "ul" elem.s and assign [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event
  handlers.
- In each event handler, we pick all the 'following' siblings 'until' a
  non-p element is found by using this selector ":not(p)". See [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/), [not](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/not.html)
- After we pick the siblings, we just extract the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) out of them.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain it also

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").nextAll('p').each(function(){
         $(this).click(function(){
              alert($(this).text());
         });
    });
});
```

Please check out this http://jsfiddle.net/UMquF/

Comment: it is working only when i cliced on p tag :) i need when ul clicked